# Is it better to download and work on Visual Studio than Visual Basic 6 , to work on visual basic?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic

is it possible to work in Visual Studio software on Visual Basic language??
  and is it even better to work on Visaul Studio than on Visaul Basic 6(VB6) software...??
  or is it that Visual Basic language must only be worked in Visual Basic 6 software, and not in Visual Studio??

Comment: VB6 is not VB.NET, the word "better" is simply wrong. Unclear what you are asking...

Comment: vb6 is not vb.net. vb6 is a dreadful language. The creator of the language (Alen Cooper) says he can not believe that people use it.

Comment: A license to Visual Basic 6 has not been sold in over a decade and half.  Since Visual Basic 6 is not free software and is not official supported on anything except Windows XP and earlier, you are better of, using supported software.

Answer (score 4):

Visual studio is the IDE used for Visual Basic programming.

If you install Visual Basic 6, you are installing a stripped down version of visual studio which contains only the components needed to run VB6.

If you install Visual studio, you will be installing the additional components for other languages at the same time.

Either way, the look and feel is almost identical, both will allow you to build VB6 applications and you will still be maintaining (very) legacy code!

On a side note - look to move to .net isf possible.. its cleaner, generally easier to work with, better resources online (for help) and will be worth the investment to learn. You can also get a copy of vb.net for free from Visual Studio Express (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs)